# getting java error after updating android studio

Tags: android, flutter

I have updated my android studio. Now I am not able to build my project.

> What went wrong:
>
> The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

When I tried to check javaHome getting this in my terminal:

```
C:\Users\xtpl>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18.0.2.1
```

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-java-gradle-migration-guide

You can look into this